# Read formatted data with d3.dsv.parseRows

Tags: javascript, d3.js, formatting

I am starting to learn javascript and d3.js (version 3.3.3). I need to read data from files with a format which is neither `csv` nor `tsv`. I could probably use [d3.dsv.parseRows](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-dsv), but I'm kind of stuck with it - I'd really appreciate some help to get started, an example would be great.

The data format is ASCII, two columns of numbers separated by an unknown number of whitespace characters (tabs or spaces). The comment character is `#`.

```
# Example 
# The data is obviously poorly aligned
# The two values in each row are separated 
# by one or more tabs and/or spaces
#
1.0   10.00
  2.0    20
3.0     30.          # this data line should be read
#  4.0    40.0       # this data line should be ignored
5.0   50.00
```

I need to have the data in an array of arrays of numbers, so I can go on with some nice d3 plotting:

```
[ [1.0,10.0], [2.0,20.0], [3.0,30.0], [5.0,50.0] ]
```

Comment: In cases like this it is usually easier to use a script to preprocess the data into JSON that you can then read without problems in D3.

Comment: Unfortunately it is out of my hands to preprocess the data files, there is a massive amount of them and they come from a third-party source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you'l have to write your own request, I've made a start on one with a couple of notes below, you'll need to finish it off though ...

```
var dsvFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    dsvFile.open("GET", "dsv.txt", true);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status === 200 || 
            req.status === 0) {

            var data = req.responseText;
            cleanData(data)
          }
        }
      };

    req.open('GET', "dsv.txt", true);
    req.send(null);

    var cleanData = function(data) {

      var clean = [];
      var lines = data.split("\n");

      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var comment = /^#/
        var whiteSpace = /^\s+/
        var OK = comment.exec(lines[i]) // check for comment lines
        var white = whiteSpace.exec(lines[i]) // check white whitespace at begining of line
        if(!OK) // if no comments then
          { 
            if(white) // if whitespace at begining of line remove 
            {
              var str = lines[i].replace(whiteSpace, '')
            } 
            else 
            {
              var str = lines[i]
            }
          clean.push(str)
          }
      };

      console.log(clean)

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To process data files with multiple spaces (and maybe more complicated pattern),
[d3.text](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#text) can be combined with a regex and then [d3.csvParseRows](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parseRows)

```
var a = [];
d3.text("http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/ftp/J/AJ/159/187/table3.dat")
     .then(function(d){a = d3.csvParseRows(d.replace(/ +/g, ","))})
```

Note due to CORS, urls will work only for some webpages.